# jquery create and return DOM element on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have button that creates a div on click. I want to return this created div when I click a button. But the following code actually returns this button.

```
 var create = $('#create').on('click', function(e){

    var content = $('<div class="foo"/>')
     
    return content

})

var test = create.trigger('click')

 console.log(test)
```

Result is:

```
init [div#create, context: document, selector: '#create']
```

Is this not possible to do this this way or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling a variable ("create") which stores the event listener on the button. This is what it looks like:

```
var test = $('#create').on('click', function(e){

    var content = $('<div class="foo"/>')
     
    return content

}).trigger('click')

console.log(test)
```

This is the solution:

###### jQuery

```
var create = function() {
  return $('<div class="foo"/>');
};
var createEl = $('#create');
createEl.on('click', function() {
  console.log(create());
  // <div class="foo"></div>
});
createEl.trigger("click");
```

###### JavaScript

```
var create = function() {
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  el.className = "foo";
  // Add other attributes if you'd like
  return el;
};
var createEl = document.querySelector('#create');
createEl.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log(create());
  // <div class="foo"></div>
});
createEl.click();
```

(jQuery) Live example

```js
var create = function() {
  return $('<div class="foo"/>');
};
var createEl = $('#create');
createEl.on('click', function() {
  console.log(create());
  // <div class="foo"></div>
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="create">Create</button>
```

(JavaScript) Live example

```
var create = function() {
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  el.className = "foo";
  // Add other attributes if you'd like
  return el;
};
var createEl = document.querySelector('#create');
createEl.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log(create());
  // <div class="foo"></div>
});
createEl.trigger("click");
```

```js
var create = function() {
  var el = document.createElement('div');
  el.className = "foo";
  // Add other attributes if you'd like
  return el;
};
var createEl = document.querySelector('#create');
createEl.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log(create());
  // <div class="foo"></div>
});
```

```html
<button id="create">Create</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. You can add a function which will be executed in your event handler to do something with the object you create in the listener:

```js
var create = $('#create').on('click', function(e){

    var content = $('<div class="foo"/>')
     
    doSomething(content)

})

create.trigger('click')

function doSomething(test) {
    console.log(test)
}
```

There is no other way and it is because the handler function assigned with `.on()` method is called when the browser triggers an event (or you use `.trigger()` method) and the return statement is used only to force calling `event.stopPropagation()` and `event.preventDefault()` methods (you have to return `false` in the handler or just assign `false` instead of a function as an event handler - check the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/on/), section *The event handler and its environment*) and not to return any value when you trigger an event manually.

You can also use an external variable to store the data "generated" in your event handler:

```js
const divs = []

var create = $('#create').on('click', function(e){

    var content = $('<div class="foo"/>')
    
    divs.push(content)

    doSomething()

})

create.trigger('click')

function doSomething() {
    console.dir(divs)
}
```